# Laravel, Eloquent: Relationships. Write two entities in 1 line

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

There are 3 entities. Article, User and Category.
Article

```
class Article extends Model{
  public function user()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

 public function category()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

User

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
public function articles()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
  }
```

Category

```
class Category extends Model{
public function articles()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
  }
}
```

To save the user who created the article in the database, I use the following code in the controller:

```
    class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
      $user = Auth::user();
      $article = new Article(['name' => 'test']);

      //save record
      $user->articles()->save($article);
}
```

}

But I also need to keep the category of the article in the table with articles.
I receive the article category in the controller:

```
$category = Category::find(2);
```

But how do I save these two entities ($user and $category) inside $article. I need to have two cells in the articles table - user_id and category_id.
Tell me please.

Answer (score 2):

Set the ids manually:

```
$article->user_id = Auth::id();
$article->category_id = $category->id;
$article->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `associate` method.

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $category = Category::first(); // find category

        $article = Article::create(['name' => 'test']); //save record

        $article->user()->associate($user); 
        $article->category()->associate($category);
    }
}
```

Comment: with what method to save in the database?

Comment: As you can see, `create` saves it to the database.

Comment: If I use this code - error. ErrorException in AppServiceProvider.php line 34: Trying to get property of non-object. https://imgur.com/a/dZg4P23

Comment: Do you have a category at index 1?

Comment: Try filling in the timestamps. Some DB managers allow you to put `NOW()` and it will automatically insert the timestamp.

Comment: I filled in the timestamps, but the error did not disappear https://imgur.com/a/8jf7vMK

Comment: Can you describe more about the error? Like what line is the issue on? Or dd() at differenet points.